# Data Frame has no values

Tags: python, pandas

This is the code I wrote but when I print the train_test_missing_df it only shows 3 columns...but no Values in it!!!

```
def missing_data_analysis(dataset,title,col):
    list_missing_data=[]
    for column_name in dataset:
        temp=(column_name,dataset[column_name].isnull().sum(),
              dataset[column_name].isnull().sum()/dataset.shape[0])
        list_missing_data.append(temp)
        
        missing_data_df=pd.DataFrame(data=list_missing_data,columns=['Feature_col',col,'Percent'])
        missing_data_df=missing_data_df[missing_data_df[col]>0].sort_values(col,ascending=False)
        return missing_data_df
train_test_missing_df=missing_data_analysis(train_test_df,'Missing feature column Data Analysis','missing_count')
train_test_missing_df
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8YK9.png)

Comment: Please provide a constructor of a sample of your dataframe to reproduce your problem. Also, kindly read [ask].

Comment: I think you should write `return missing_data_df` outside `for` loop ? Also you are passing dataframe to function but in the function you are looping over datafram instead of `dataset.columns` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write return missing_data_df outside for loop ? Also you are passing dataframe to function but in the function you are looping over datafram instead of dataset.columns ? –
Deepak Tripathi

This is the right answer